# XML - External access

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am planning on saving content of some HTML sites in XML docs. These XML docs will be publicly available to read, however, are there vulnerabilities that could allow outsiders to write to my XML docs? I'll be using simpleXML (PHP script) to allow logged in users to edit their own XML doc.

Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: A vulnerability would probably only exist if you've created one in your XML editing implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If the permissions on the XML files are read-only for the public (775 at most), and only logged-in users can edit via PHP, then you shouldn't have anything to worry about.